# how can i extract multiple digits from a whole number directly into variables?

Tags: python

I need to extract the tens,hundreds,thousandths,etc from a whole number into multiple variables:a should be the unit, b the tens, c the hundreds etc...
I would thank you a lot if you could help me.

Comment: You should at least add some sample input and the expected output

Comment: You should use the modulo `%` operator.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy way to do it:

```
list(map(int, str(your_number)))
```

for instance if you put `456` in that:

```
 list(map(int, str(456)))
```

output will be:

```
[4,5,6]
```

then you can assign it to variables if you sure about its length:

```
a, b ,c = list(map(int, str(456)))
```

then `a is 4` and `b is 5` and `c is 6`.

Answer (score 1):

If you exactly want a, b, c, d to store the values as mentioned, You can use this example. Assuming the number is 123456

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as al 
num = 123456

l = len(str(num))

vars_used = al[:l]

for var, val in zip(vars_used, str(num)[::-1]):
    locals()[var] = val


for var in vars_used:
    print(var, '=', str(eval(var)))
```

Output will be:

```
a = 6
b = 5
c = 4
d = 3
e = 2
f = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

2 options:
Iterate over the digits by using modulo 10 on the number.

OR

Turn it into a string and just access it with list slicing. 
Example: `"12345"[1:3]` is `"23"`
And convert it however you wish to use it.